# How do I insert 4 byte unicode characters into mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, unicode, utf-8, utf-32

I'm occasionally getting following exception when someone tries to insert smiley into my database:

`Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A' for column 'name' at row 1`

The name is defined as

```
`name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf32 COLLATE utf32_general_ci NOT NULL,`
```

And I'm using `CharSet=utf8;` in my connection string

What else should I check/change for full unicode insert to start working?

Comment: Do not use `utf32`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change your `collation` of database `table` to `utf8mb4_bin`

And set CHARACTER SET in database configuration as `utf8mb4`

Comment: I'm executing `alter table mytable convert to character set utf8 collate utf8mb4_bin;` and getting following error: `COLLATION 'utf8mb4_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'`

Comment: ok. fixed http://joncarlmatthews.com/2015/09/07/error-1253-42000-collation-utf8mb4_unicode_ci-is-not-valid-for-character-set-utf8/